# AngularJS not refreshing ng-repeat on page change

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to bind data to my Laravel app. I'm also using Bootstrap-UI for pagination, and so far, things are working together at first.

When I change to page 2, the ng-repeat won't show the data from page 2. I already checked and the $scope.results is changing with the data from page2, but ng-repeat won't show it. It's blank.

I tried placing $scope.$watch but I always get an error saying that $digest is already in progress.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in filtered = results | filter:search | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit" class="results-table">
    <td class="text-center">
         [[ result.id ]]
    </td>
    <td>
         [[ result.name ]]
    </td>
    <td>
         [[ result.email ]]
    </td>
    <td>
         [[ result.cpf ]]
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
         <span class="label label-sm" ng-class="{true: 'label-success', false: 'label-danger'}[result.active == 'Ativo']">
            [[ result.active ]]
         </span>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil font-blue"></i></a>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-remove font-red-flamingo"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My pagination HTML (bootstrap-ui)

```
<pagination class="pull-right" ng-change="getResults(currentPage)" ng-model="currentPage" num-pages="numPages" total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="entryLimit"></pagination>
```

And my Angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('prime', ['ngSanitize','ngResource','angular-loading-bar','ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap'],  
 function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});


app.factory('JsonService', function ($resource,model) {
    return $resource('/api/users/?page=:page',{page: "@page"});
});

app.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        if (input) {
            start = +start;
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    };
});

app.controller('ResultsController', function($scope, $http, JsonService, filterFilter) {

    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.search = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.entryLimit = 10; // itens por pagina

    $scope.init = function() {
        JsonService.get({}, function (response) {
            $scope.results = response.data;
            $scope.totalItems = response.total;
            $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);           
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.results = [];
        });
    };

    $scope.resetFilters = function () {
        $scope.search = [];
    };

    // runs $watch on the search field
    $scope.$watch('search', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.results, newVal);
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
    }, true);

    $scope.$watch('currentPage', function(newPage) {
        $scope.init($scope.numberPage);
    });  

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your example accurate? There are a few confusing parts to it which could be related to your problem:

1. Your `$scope.init()` method never passes a `page` parameter to the `.get()` method. Because of this, your service is probably returning the same page every time.
2. Your `$watch('currentPage', ...)` call watches `currentPage`, but passes `$scope.numberPage` to the `$scope.init()` method. Even if the problem in #1 didn't exist, I think you meant to use `currentPage` here instead of `numberPage`.
3. You're performing client-side pagination as well as server-side pagination:

   ```
   <tr ng-repeat="result in filtered = results | filter:search | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit" class="results-table">
   ```

   Specifically, this part:

   ```
   startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit
   ```

   Your `entryLimit` is set to 10, right? So let's say you request page 2 and the server returns 10 items (assuming problems #1 and #2 didn't exist). Your filters would evaluate to this:

   ```
   startFrom:(2-1)*10 | limitTo:10
   ```

   Which comes out to:

   ```
   startFrom:10 | limitTo:10
   ```

   But you only have 10 items because the server already did the pagination! By doing the client-side pagination as well, you end up with an empty list.

   So, either get rid of the client-side pagination (the `startFrom` and `limitTo`), or get rid of the server-side pagination (load everything once in the beginning).

That's all I can see from your code. If you can post a full example on Plunker or something, we might be able to help more.

Comment: It works thanks! Points #1 and #2 were not the cause, it was my mistake when trying to paste the example code (my code is slightly different). I had to remove the startFrom and limitTo from ng-repeat and not it's working perfectly.